# Parent site logo is back to "Food and Cooking Beta". Meta is still "Seasoned Advice"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, logo

I had seen it as "Seasoned Advice" for a while, so I assume its a bug of some sort.

> [image]

The meta site still says "Seasoned Advice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a hard refresh (control on non-OS X systems, command on OS X systems along with F5 or your refresh button).  It should be Seasoned Advice.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I must not have checked the site from my work computer for a while. Thanks!